# unity 2d how to stop all movement towards a collider to prevent an entity from shaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is simple: I have a player with a rigidbody 2d and a collider 2d attached to it and I have a wall with a collider 2d attached to it. When I move the player against the wall they do collide but my player starts to shake really fast and it looks like it wants to pass through the wall.

GIF: http://gph.is/2ENK3ql

I need the player to stop moving when it collides with a wall and to deny any further movement towards the wall without disrupting movement away from the wall.

Player movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
// Variables
public bool moving = true;
float playerMovSpeed = 5.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (moving == true)
    {
        PlayerMove();
    }
    PlayerMoveCheck();
}

public void Set_moving(bool val)
{
    moving = val;
}

void PlayerMove()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * playerMovSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * playerMovSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * playerMovSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerMovSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}

void PlayerMoveCheck()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) != true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) != true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) != true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) != true)
    {
        moving = false;
    }
    else
    {
        moving = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code relevant to the player moving and colliding with the wall.

Comment: I added the code to the question. The wall doesn't contain any code, just a collider 2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform.Translate() essentially acts as a teleportation of your transform. This means that your player is being put into its new coordinates, and then sees there is a collision and pushes it out - which is why your character "vibrates" against the wall. Instead, you should consider adding a [rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) to your player and modifying the movement using `.velocity` or `.position` or ".AddForce()" which will take the physics of the collision into the account during movement.

You can do something like the following for force movement:

```
void Update()
{
    rbody.velocity = rbody.velocity * .9f; // custom friction

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        rbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        rbody.AddForce(Vector2.down * speed);
    // repeat for A and D
}
```

Comment: unfortunately transform.position has the same effect when colliding. I already had a rigidbody attached to the player.

Comment: rigidbody.position is what you will need to use. or rigidbody.velocity

Comment: Used this piece of code: playerRigidB.position += Vector2.up * playerMovSpeed * Time.deltaTime; the playerRigidB is the variable that holds the rigidbody2d. Still gives the same results when colliding.

Comment: Velocity seems to fix the collision problem but gives me the weirdest movement.

Comment: you applied the rigidbody.position movement to all of your input keys? it should work similar to velocity. changes to the rigidbody.position are only applied to the transform after the physics step.

Comment: I applied it to all of my input keys. It looks like it's skating on ice now.

Comment: unrelated, but you can simplify your code by using .GetKeyDown instead of .GetKey and removing your PlayerMoveCheck()

Comment: yes, if you are using velocity you will either have to add friction or set the velocity back to zero when a key is not being pressed.

Comment: I'll just try and look how to create velocity based movement. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. I added some code to my answer that might help.

Comment: Almost works but I have one simple problem. When I hold down the W and 1 second later hold down the W and the D button it won't go diagonally it'll choose to go up.

Comment: hah okay, I tweaked my answer again. you will have to tune some values to get the correct speed. my velocity code just set velocity in a single direction, addforce is additive. either would work but you will have to play around with them to get the result you want.

Comment: Right. This eleminates the colliding issue! Thank you so much. I even gained some knowledge about rigidbodies! One quick question though: When I collide with another entity like a player or enemy my force gets applied to that entity. Lets say I walk into an enemy, that enemy gets thrown backwards into the wall. Is there a way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: one way to go about it would be to set the mass of your player very low so it has no effect on your heavier other objects (this will mess up the force added to control the player which is why rigidbody.position is recommended).

Comment: Does rigidbody.position mess with the colliders again though?

Comment: yes. rigidbody makes use of the physics. [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

Comment: alright thank you Rye. I'll just have to choose or find a way around it.